# OLS: Omitted variable bias when $\mathbb{E}$(omitted variable) $\neq 0$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, least-squares

The proof for omitted variable bias is pretty simple, via [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias#In_linear_regression):

Assume the true model is $$Y = X\beta + Z\delta + U$$

and we estimate naively $$Y = X\beta + W$$

The OLS estimate of the incorrectly specified model is then $$\beta = [X^TX]^{-1}X^TY = [X^TX]^{-1}X^T[X\beta + Z\delta + U] = \beta + [X^TX]^{-1}X^T[Z\delta + U]$$

And taking the expectation conditional on $X$ (assuming $U$ is mean zero and independent of $X$): $$\mathbb{E}[\beta\vert X] = \beta + [X^TX]^{-1}\mathbb{E}[X^TZ\vert X]\delta$$

The standard proof then shows that our estimate of $\beta$ will be biased if $X$ and $Z$ are correlated.

**But what if the mean of $X$ and $Z$ are both nonzero?** For example, assume $Z$ is independent of $X$ and that $\mathbb{E}X\neq 0 \neq \mathbb{E}Z$.

Then we have 
$$\mathbb{E}[\beta\vert X] = \beta + [X^TX]^{-1}\mathbb{E}[X^TZ\vert X]\delta = \beta + [X^TX]^{-1}X^T\mathbb{E}[Z]\delta \neq \beta $$

**Doesn't that mean, then, that our estimate of $\beta$ can be biased even if the omitted variable is independent of the other regressors if $\mathbb{E}Z>0$**

Answer (score 2):

It is true, as long as you don't include the intercept in the regression (a column of 1's in the $X$ matrix).

If you do include an intercept, then

$Y=X\beta+\delta Z+U$

Let's assume that the first column of $X$ is a column of 1's then

$Y=1_n\beta_1+X_{-1}\beta_{-1}+\delta Z+U$

Where $X_{-1}$ represents the $X$ matrix without the first column (define $\beta_{-1}$ analogously)

It can be proven that this can be rewritten as

$Y=1_n\bar Y+X_{-1}^M\beta_{-1}+\delta Z^M+U$

Where $Z^M=Z-\bar Z$ and $X^M$ is defined analogously (by centering each variable).

Now, it follows that the estimator of $\beta_{-1}$ is simply $(X_{-1}^{'M}X_{-1}^M)^{-1}X_{-1}^{'M}Y$ because each column of $X_{-1}^M$ is orthogonal to $1_n$.

Now, because of the orthogonality it also follows that $\hat\beta_{-1}$ is unbiased since

$E((X_{-1}^{'M}X_{-1}^M)^{-1}X_{-1}^{'M}Y)=E((X_{-1}^{'M}X_{-1}^M)^{-1}X_{-1}^{'M}(1_n\bar Y+X_{-1}^M\beta_{-1}+\delta Z^M+U))=\hat\beta_{-1}$

Comment: But that still leaves you with $\mathbb{E}[\beta\vert X] = \beta + [X^TX]^{-1}X^T\mathbb{E}[(Z^* + \mu_z)]\delta  = \beta + [X^TX]^{-1}X^T\mathbb{E}[Z]\delta \neq \beta $ I don't see how that's different.

Comment: Because you will get $E[Z^*]$ not $Z$. The $\delta\mu_z$ gets absorbed by the $\beta_i$ that corresponds to the intercept. So $\beta$ is unbiased except for $\beta_i$ because $\hat\beta_i$ now estimates $\beta_i+\delta\mu_z$.

Comment: Why would it only impact the intercept? If you assume $\delta = [1, 1, ..., 1]$ for example the bias at each element of $\beta$ will be $\mu_x$ times the contribution of $[X^TX]^{-1}X^T$.

Comment: I guess I'm just confused how this matches up with $\hat{\beta} = \beta + [X^TX]^{-1}X^T\mu\delta$ as I had it, because that must mean that $[X^TX]^{-1}X^T\mu_x\delta = [bias, 0]^T$ assuming $\beta = [\beta_1, \beta_{-1}]^T$. But that doesn't really seem right to me...

Comment: Yes, the mean of $Z$ has an effect on $\beta_1$ but not on the other coefficients.

Comment: Right, but that must mean that $[X^TX]^{-1}X^T = [A,0]^T$ assuming $\mu_x$ and $\delta$ are constants (for some A). How can that be possible?

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with what you write, I'm just confused how what I write and what you write are equivalent.

Comment: It means that $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T1_n=(A,0)^T$ and this is true as long as $X$ has a column of 1's. But might be very hard to see directly....

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.